# JQuery GetOrgChart - Boxescolor and URL

Tags: orgchart

I am trying GetOrgChart and have a question, it is possible to change boxes color, however I did not find a way to change the color of boxes based on a filter (ie if you are boys the boxes are blue and pink for girls). I know about the event renderBoxContentEvent but I was not able to find a way to use it to modify the color of the box

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following demo: http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Box-Color

It demonstrates exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks I saw the demo, however the code look like
`boxesColor: [
            { id: 2, color: "blue" },
   { id: 3, color: "lightteal" }
        ]`
In the example id is harcoded and I can't figure a way to replace ie id:2 by a condition, for example (simplified) `if sex=male then color is blue else if sex=female then color is pink else color is grey`
`

Comment: I tried something like this `             setBoxColor: function( sender, args ) {
                    if (args.Sex == "Male")
                    args.boxesColor.push({ id: args.id, color: "blue"});
                    },` with no success, I can't figure out a way to set the color of the box based on a filter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and made a workaround which is surely not very nice, but it is working.

Set up 2 arrays where you collect the ids depending on the data.Sex's outcome.

```
var warr = new Array(); // array for the women
var marr = new Array(); // array for the men

$('#people').getOrgChart({
            renderBoxContentEvent: function( sender, args ) {
                if (args.data.Sex == "Female") {warr.push(args.id);}
                if (args.data.Sex == "Male")  {marr.push(args.id);}
            },  
                primaryColumns: ["Name"],
                editable: true,
                dataSource: [
            { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Sex : "Female"},
            { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Sex : "Female"},
            { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Ben Johnson", Sex : "Male"}]

            });

            // now loop through the arrays to color the boxes   
            for (var i = 0; i < warr.length; i++) {$("#people").getOrgChart("setBoxColor",warr[i],"lightgreen");} // girls green
            for (var i = 0; i < marr.length; i++) {$("#people").getOrgChart("setBoxColor",marr[i],"lightblue");} // men blue
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the demo (http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Box-Color), there is JQuery code to set the box color of a particular index in the datasource:

```
$("#people").getOrgChart("setBoxColor", 6, "green");
```